# How to make link in message body with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python to send email. There is a message that should contain link where a file for download can be find. I want that a receiver of email can click on the link and open that path.
Thank you.

Comment: We would need the e-mail code you're using in order to help you. Most likely you're using plain-text emailing code which won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from_adr='foo@example.com'
to_adr='bar@example.com'

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Emailing a link"
msg['From'] = from_adr
msg['To'] = to_adr

html = """
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Link:</p>
    <a href="http://www.somewhere.com/whatever.foo">Link Text</a>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1=MIMEText(html, 'html')
part2=MIMEText("Link:\nhttp://www.somewhere.com/whatever.foo", 'text')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(from_adr, to_adr, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Note: this will send an html email with a text part as a fallback. The link won't work in the text part.. because it's just text!

Comment: Thank you for making me aware that I am using text part. I didn't think about that.

Comment: I know this post is 6 years old... Hopefully, you'll see this. In what situation would the "text" version of the message (the variable you have listed as part2) send? Are there certain email clients that are unable to process html? Certain browsers? Devices?